# Decoding a 1 Byte Date into Year, Month and Day

Tags: java

I got an int Date in 16 bits. The first seven bits (from left to right) are used to describe the Year, the next 4 are used for the Month, the remaining 5 are for the Day. I need to separate the respective 7, 4 and 5 bits from the original 16 bits (Year is 1111111000000000; Month is 0000000111100000; Day is 0000000000011111).

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code. And you will find [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) useful.

Comment: Google [`java bit manipulation`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+bit+manipulation).

Comment: So what is the question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I did. Tried to do int year = (date &1111111000000000)>>>9; but didnt work out.

Comment: 16 bits is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated solution:**

I'm still not sure whether this is what OP is looking as no concrete code was stated in his question.

Similarly he did not state what the expected output would be, all we know now was that a 16 bit binary was given to OP, and he will need to figure out the binary codes for the Year, Month and Day through certain bit position.

Once the binary has been captured then convert the binary bits into numeric values, which then it is used for further comparison. For instance, year value of > 100 means it is year > 2000.

**My solution:**

```
private long unsetBit(long value, int pos) { return value & ~(1<<pos); }

private long getYear(long value) { return value >> /*total 0 in month and day=*/9; }

private long getMonthDay(long value) {
    int[] leftBitPos = new int[]{ 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10 };
    for (Integer position : leftBitPos) value = unsetBit(value, position);
    return value;
}

private long getMonth(long value) {
    value = getMonthDay(value);
    return value >> /*total 0 in day=*/5;
}

private long getDay(long value) {
    int[] leftBitPos = new int[]{ 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
    for (Integer position : leftBitPos) value = unsetBit(value, position);
    return value;
}

private void doIt() {
    long fullDate = 0b1111111110100001;
     System.out.println("Year binary: " + getYear(fullDate));
     System.out.println("Month binary: " + getMonth(fullDate));
     System.out.println("Day binary: " + getDay(fullDate));
```

> Year binary: 127 
>   Month binary: 29 
>  
>   Day binary: 1

**Old solution, the regexpr way.**

Assuming OP has the luxury to convert the binary value into a piece of String and then also assuming he is just interested in the binary code for the "Year", "Month" and "Day".

I would propose doing a simple `capture` regular expression to look for the 0s and 1s for a particular date and then process the captured values further by padding some zeros to it. Or alternatively if you don't like using regexpr you can look at doing a string.substring and do the same, padding it with zeros.

Recommend using the regexpr;
`^(?=[0-1]{16})([0-1]{7})([0-1]{4})([0-1]{5})`

Essentially what this does is;

1. From the first character `^`
2. `(?=[0-1]{16)` Check and see if there is 16 zero and one characters in the string
3. From the first character capture the first 7 `0` and `1`, `([0-1]{7})` for the year.
4. Do the same for month and day respectively through `([0-1]{4})([0-1]{5})`

Now prefix and pad your year month and day result values with the appropriate amount of zeroes.

**Example:**

```
final String YEAR_PADDING = "0000000";
final String MONTH_PADDING = "0000";
final String DAY_PADDING = "00000";

private void doIt() {

    Pattern binaryDateFormat = Pattern.compile("^(?=[0-1]{16})([0-1]{7})([0-1]{4})([0-1]{5})");
    Matcher m = binaryDateFormat.matcher("1111111111100000");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Year binary: " + m.group(1) + MONTH_PADDING + DAY_PADDING);
        System.out.println("Month binary: " + YEAR_PADDING + m.group(2) + DAY_PADDING);
        System.out.println("Day binary: " + YEAR_PADDING + MONTH_PADDING + m.group(3));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> Year binary: 1111111000000000 
>   Month binary: 0000000111100000 
>   Day binary: 0000000000000000

Comment: @GMP_47 hope this works for you happy to discuss further

Comment: I cannot define it as a method. I get the int from "int date = buffer.getInt();" I just need to know how to multiply Date by 1111111000000000 and then shift right 9 in Java.

Comment: Apologise if I didn't understood your question correctly but without concrete code I could only make out what you want from the text. Ok. So what is `date`? How does the value look like? You wanted to shift the binary because you wanted just the first 7 digits here? Also, why can't you convert the Int into String and plug into my example code and tweak the output accordingly?

Comment: I'm using ByteBuffer for Wrapping all Bytes from a .dat so I can grab every 2 Bytes and show them on screen. The binary line I'm trying to read is this Byte that has the Date. Once I get the first 7 bits(a) from Date, I can get the year: a<100 then Year is 2000+a; if a>=100 then Year is 1999-a+100.
Sorry, I shouldnt have mentioned the whole Date thing, I just need to know how to separate 7, 4 and 5 bits from a Byte.

Comment: @GMP_47  no worries. Just trying my best to help you out. I have updated my solution. Please let me know whether is that what you are looking for? Basically the solution takes in a 16 bit binary then work out the day, month and year's numeric value. E.g. Year resolves to 127, so that is Year 2000 for your case. Let me know whether this helps. Thanks

Comment: what's long fullDate = 0b1111111110100001; for?
Does it work if the 2 Bytes that are the Date I save it as int date = buffer.getInt()? Why do you have Longint in your code (4 Bytes)?

Comment: `long fullDate = 0b111` is just to mimic what your API would return. Obviously I don't have the luxury to replicate the problem using your API so that is the closest I can think of. If you need to go with integer then just replace long with int. They are the same, it is just that long has a greater max value than integer, which is 2147483647 for int.